# Row-wise average for a subset of columns with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a 'DataFrame` which has occasional missing values, and looks something like this:

```
          Monday         Tuesday         Wednesday 
      ================================================
Mike        42             NaN               12
Jenna       NaN            NaN               15
Jon         21              4                 1
```

I'd like to add a new `column` to my data frame where I'd calculate the average across all `columns` for every `row`.

Meaning, for `Mike`, I'd need 
`(df['Monday'] + df['Wednesday'])/2`, but for `Jenna`, I'd simply use `df['Wednesday amt.']/1`

Does anyone know the best way to account for this variation that results from missing values and calculate the average?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can simply:

```
df['avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)

       Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday        avg
Mike       42      NaN         12  27.000000
Jenna     NaN      NaN         15  15.000000
Jon        21        4          1   8.666667
```

because `.mean()` ignores missing values by default: [see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

To select a subset, you can:

```
df['avg'] = df[['Monday', 'Tuesday']].mean(axis=1)

       Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday   avg
Mike       42      NaN         12  42.0
Jenna     NaN      NaN         15   NaN
Jon        21        4          1  12.5
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Is there any way I can exclude a selection of the columns without creating a new data frame altogether, or would I have to create a new df out of a subset of df, run `df.mean(axis=1)`, and then merge that with the original data frame?

Comment: @stallingOne https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Answer (score 13):

Alternative - using iloc (can also use loc here):

```
df['avg'] = df.iloc[:,0:2].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

Resurrecting this Question because all previous answers currently print a Warning.

In most cases, use `assign()`:

```
df = df.assign(avg=df.mean(axis=1))
```

For specific columns, one can input them by name:

```
df = df.assign(avg=df.loc[:, ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]].mean(axis=1))
```

Or by index, using one more than the last desired index as it is not inclusive:

```
df = df.assign(avg=df.iloc[:,0:3]].mean(axis=1))
```

Answer (score -2):

Using apply method:

```
df['avg'] = df[['Monday', 'Tuesday']].apply(np.avg, axis = 1)
```