# Calculate Mean for each CSV row

Tags: python, csv

i have 3 csv files named file1, file2, file3.
Each CSV is filled with 3 Columns and 5653 rows:

```
1   0   -95
2   0   -94
3   0   -93
...
51  0   -93
0   1   -92
1   1   -91
2   1   -90
..
```

First column is a X variable 2nd is a y variable, 3rd is a measured value from which I want to have the mean.

What I want to do is:

- read first row of file 1
- read first row of file 2
- read first row of file 3 and then count the mean of the measured value.

So for example:

```
file1 row1 -98 
file2 row1 -97
file3 row1 -95

mean 96,666666667
```

i want to write that mean into a new csv file with the following format

```
 1,0,mean_of_row1 (which would be 96,666666667)
 2,0,mean_of_row2
 3,0,mean_of_row3
 4,0,mean_of_row4
```

currently im able to calculate the mean of the measurement column of each file and store it as a row in a results file

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv_file_list = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"]
result_csv = "result.csv"

with open(result_csv, 'wb') as rf:
    for idx, csv_file in enumerate(csv_file_list):
        csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file).values
        mean_measured = np.mean(csv_data[:, 2])
        rf.write(','.join([str(0), str(idx), str(mean_measured)+"\n"]))
```

But how can fulfill my intention?
Thanks so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, Pandas is really helpful. You can avoid all looping and neatly read csv into dataframe. Then join all three dataframes into one and calculate the [pandas.DataFrame.mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) of the required fields in row wise.

[pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has the option to limit the number of rows using nrows parameter.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv('file1.txt',names=['x1','Y1','Value1'],nrows=5356)
df2=pd.read_csv('file2.txt',names=['x2','Y2','Value2'],nrows=5356)
df3=pd.read_csv('text3.txt',names=['x3','Y3','Value3'],nrows=5356)

df_concat= pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)
print df_concat


df_concat['meanvalue']=df_concat[['Value1','Value2','Value3']].mean(axis=1)
print(df_concat.to_csv(columns=['meanvalue'],index=False))
```

output

```
meanvalue
-96.5
-97.0
-86.0
-95.0
```

Comment: that should be okay if you have enough memory

Comment: is there a way to only print the meanvalue? like print df_concat['meanvalue'] without the index?

Comment: `for a in range (0,5356,1): data=df_concat['meanvalue'][a]` did it for me because i need exactly 5356 rows

Comment: updated the answer, now this code only reads first 5356 rows and prints meanvalue without index

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to make one large pandas table in that case using [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). The join value will need to be the index of the respective dataframe.

This way, you can join where the x and y value are the same. You will end up with 5 columns, x,y and the following 3 columns will be your values you want to calculate from. Now, you can simply create a new column that measures the mean across the last 3 values in a row for the dataframe. x or y, whichever is unique can be made as the index.

The pandas [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) function should help you merge based on the rows themselves.

The SQL equivalent of what you are doing is an inner join on the y values, which I assume are unique per csv file.

Comment: But how am i able to read a row of a specific column? Like Row1 Column2 Row2 Column2 with `np.mean(csv_data[:, 2])` it only looks into the columns

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734940/in-pandas-how-to-get-average-of-several-column-values-for-each-row-in-data-fram) should help you take the average across columns.