# Calculate average between columns in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

| State | %internet2016 | %internet2018 | %white 2016 | %white 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QLD | 85 | 90 | 85 | 82 |
| NSW | 83 | 92 | 80 | 72 |
| WA | 82 | 88 | 82 | 78 |
| SA | 86 | 86 | 88 | 84 |
| TAS | 78 | 80 | 92 | 88 |
| NT | 48 | 65 | 76 | 75 |

My goal is to create a dataset like this

| State | %internet2016-2018 | %white2016-2018 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QLD | 87.5 | 83.5 |
| NSW | 87.5 | 76 |
| WA | 85 | 80 |
| SA | 86 | 86 |
| TAS | 79 | 90 |
| NT | 56.5 | 75.5 |

I would like to have the mean of `%internet` and `%white`.

I tried this but it was not what I want:

```
df = df["%internet2016","%internet2018"].mean()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row-wise average for a subset of columns with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734940/row-wise-average-for-a-subset-of-columns-with-missing-values), or better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366506/calculate-new-column-as-the-mean-of-other-columns-in-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the mean using this

```
df['%internet2016-2018']=(df['%internet2016']+df['%internet2018'])/2
df['%white2016-2018']= (df['%white 2016']+df['%white 2018'])/2
df=df.drop(['%internet2016', '%internet2018', '%white 2016', '%white 2018'],axis=1)
```

Result

[image: TransformedDataFrame]

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating means of `%internet` and `%white` groups of columns:

```
pd.concat([df['State'], 
           df.filter(like='%internet').pipe(lambda df: df.mean(axis=1)
                                            .rename('%internet'+'-'.join(c[-4:] for c in df.columns))),
           df.filter(like='%white').pipe(lambda df: df.mean(axis=1)
                                         .rename('%white'+'-'.join(c[-4:] for c in df.columns)))], axis=1)
```

---

```
  State  %internet2016-2018  %white2016-2018
0  QLD                 87.5             83.5
1  NSW                 87.5             76.0
2   WA                 85.0             80.0
3   SA                 86.0             86.0
4  TAS                 79.0             90.0
5   NT                 56.5             75.5
```